# How to append rows from the new page for a loop

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, for-loop, scrape

```
urls = []
for page in pages:
    page = "https://www.golddist.com/index.php?skip="+str(page)+"&m=search&instock=1"
    urls.append(page)

    #print(urls)


for pgur in urls:
    browser.get(pgur)
    time.sleep(1)

    manufs = browser.find_elements_by_xpath('/html/body/div/div[2]/div[2]/div/form/div[1]/table/tbody/tr[position()>1]/td[1]/a/b/font/span')

    Identifier = []
    for part1 in manufs:
        manuf = part1.text
        Identifier.append(manuf)
    print(Identifier)


    heads = browser.find_elements_by_xpath('/html/body/div/div[2]/div[2]/div/form/div[1]/table/tbody/tr[position()>1]/td[2]/span/a/b')

    Title = []
    for part2 in heads:
        head = part2.text
        Title.append(head)
    #print(Title)


    stocks = browser.find_elements_by_xpath('/html/body/div/div[2]/div[2]/div/form/div[1]/table/tbody/tr[position()>1]/td[3]/center/b/font/font')

    Note = []
    for part3 in stocks:
        stock = part3.text
        Note.append(stock)
    #print(Note)


    pri = browser.find_elements_by_xpath('/html/body/div/div[2]/div[2]/div/form/div[1]/table/tbody/tr[position()>1]/td[5]/center/b/font')

    Price = []
    for part4 in pri:
        pric = part4.text
        Price.append(pric)
    #print(Price)


    data = {'Identifier': Identifier, 'Title': Title, 'Price': Price, 'Note': Note}
    df = pd.DataFrame(data)

    df.to_csv('GD1.csv', index = False)
```

How can I append data from all the pages instead of keeping replacing the rows from the new page?
I want to scrape product data from all the pages. But my script is only to refresh the CSV file with the scraped data from the new page.

Answer (score 0):

Use a list to store data at each iteration and finally concatenate all results in a single dataframe:

```
ldf = []  # <- create a list to store dataframes for each url
for pgur in urls:
    browser.get(pgur)
    time.sleep(1)

    ...

    data = {'Identifier': Identifier, 'Title': Title, 'Price': Price, 'Note': Note}
    df = pd.DataFrame(data)
    ldf.append(df)  # <- append your dataframe to the list

    pd.concat(ldf).to_csv('GD1.csv', index=False)  # <- overwrite csv with all data


df = pd.concat(ldf)  # <- concatenate all dataframes
```

Comment: Thanks for answering my question. Is there a way that the CSV file can be updated with new rows after every loop? I tried your code, the only issue I see is the CSV file won't be updated until the last page is scraped, but there are more than 300 pages.

Comment: You can use this line at each iteration `pd.concat(ldf).to_csv('GD1.csv', index=False)` but it's totally suboptimal! Speed up your downloads by using `multiprocessing` to get the data faster.